# Error de conexión entre SQLSRV y PHP 7.4

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Tengo un problema con la conexión entre mi sistema y el servidor de SQL Server 2017.

Hay veces en las que al momento de realizar una consulta no tengo errores, pero en ocasiones me sale el siguiente error (se podría decir que si me ejecuta correctamente 1 vez y otra vez no):

```
> SQLSTATE : 01000 
> Código : 5701 
> Mensaje : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'mi-bd'.
```

Este es mi código de conexión

```
$serverName = "MICOMPUTADORA\\SQLEXPRESS";
$urlConnect = array("Database" => "mi-db",
                    "UID" => "sa",
                    "PWD" => "password",
                    "CharacterSet" => 'UTF-8');
$conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $urlConnect);

if (($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        die("SQLSTATE : " . $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br />" . "Código : " . $error['code'] . "<br />" . "Mensaje : " . $error['message'] . "<br />");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de una consulta generica.

```
public function executeSQL($strSQL) {
    $params = array();
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $this->resultSet = sqlsrv_query($conexion, $strSQL, $params, $options);
}
```

No se si exista algo como una conexión persistente en SqlSrv. Aquí la pregunta, porque si hay veces que ejecuta y otras veces no.

Comment: Por si alguien le sale el mismo error, ya me di cuenta que no es como tal un error 
[enlace de error](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3509), solo lo metí en otro if para omitir esta parte. Es una advertencia o código especificando a que BD de datos se esta conectando. El problema mío era que me cortaba la ejecución de otros Querys en el sistema y me bloqueaban las vistas.

Comment: De cualquier modo nunca es buena idea mostrar mensajes de error internos. Te sugiero que mejor muestres un mensaje de error genérico únicamente para errores realmente, no para advertencias. Sería relativamente fácil hacerlo, determinando qué código `SQLSTATE` son realmente errores y qué códigos son simplemente advertencias. O, mejor aún, configurando adecuadamente el estado de `WarningsReturnAsErrors` [como explica el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-configure.php) para que deje de considerar las advertencias (warnings) como errores.